# React-Native Linking.addEventListener('url', this._handleOpenURL); not listening

Tags: android, react-native, callback, actionlistener, deep-linking

In react-native, I am trying to log in the user using facebook/Google.

I am opening the URL in external browser, after entering credentials, It redirects back to app where, I have added an event

```
    componentDidMount() {
            Linking.addEventListener('url', this._handleOpenURL);
    }
```

In iOS, it is working fine.
But on Android, this never gets called.

I read somewhere that Linking works only with In app browser, I have also tried that, but Google does not allow that also. Attaching the image for that error please have a look also:

[image]

I have also gone through and alerted componentWillMount(), componentDidMount(), componentWillUpdate(), componentWillUnmount(), componentWillReceiveNewProps(), and _handleOpenURL() and I get nothing when I click the link and it "re-opens" the app from the background? What am I doing wrong?

**Can any body help me please.**
**I need extreme help. I am stuck here.**

**Please guide me how to catch URL callback for android in React-Native.**

Thanks.

Comment: **Note:** I have searched on internet. there are multiple places i found solution, but that is for iOS and that is working fine in my case. I need solution/help for Android.

Comment: Do your <intent-filter> set correctly in your AndroidMeniest.xml ?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking#handling-deep-links Have you tried Linking.getInitialURL() ?

Comment: Yes I tried that. Problem is, on returning back from browser, it is not calling the registered listener that is written in didmount. Following handler for url  is never called              
Linking.addEventListener('url', this._handleOpenURL);

Answer (score 3):

In android we have to mention the launch mode as singleTask for the activity to restrict it to load only once.

Add this line for the activity that will be opened against this redirection:

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

I had added this to **application** tag. which is wrong. It should be with **activity** tag.

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same on my android app, and I have checked that I have singleTask. Do you know any other possible solutions?